# Can I delete those items in .resx

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C# code. It is the UI and contains a .resx file. Inside this file, there are node like:

```
<data name="OK_Button.Locked" type="System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
<value>False</value>
</data>
<data name="OK_Button.DefaultModifiers" type="System.CodeDom.MemberAttributes, System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
<value>Private</value>
</data>
<data name="OK_Button.Modifiers" type="System.CodeDom.MemberAttributes, System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
<value>Private</value>
</data>
```

Can I just delete them?

Comment: Why do you want to? Do you need to reclaim 500 bytes of disk space? (Also, of course, the answer to the question *posed* is Yes - perhaps you wanted to ask what the effects would be?)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yeah, you are right, I'm just confused about what are these items for. And what are the effects would be. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely to happen when you tinkered with the Lock feature and/or the Modifiers property.  These properties are a bit special, they are not actually properties of the Button class.  They are design-time properties that only have a meaning at design time.  So the designer needs a place to store their values, they can't go in the InitializeComponent() method.  The .resx file is the alternative.

If this is a C# project then deleting these .resx entries isn't going to have any effect since they have the default values.  If it is VB.NET project then deleting is not okay, the default Modifiers is Friend, not Private.

If you do delete them then it is not unlikely that they'll just re-appear again later.  It is a battle you cannot win, it just isn't anything to worrywart about.

Comment: Good to know that, thanks! I was worrying if it is involved in build and have impact on the assembly. Thank you so much for your detailed answer!